# How do I add a subview to a view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to learn more about XCode, so I created an application that is intended for general desktop/laptop use, but not for iPhone.

It has AppController built on `#include "Foundation/Foundation.h"` and using files that I named AppController.h, AppController.m, and the MainMenu.xib file that was generated by the development system.

Now I want to add a subview.  As I work though the problem, I'm obviously leaving out something or I'm incorrectly coding something. I can find many tutorials that provide a list of steps that are intended for iPhone applications, but none that fit my non-iPhone project.

Comment: Did you search the OSX part of developer.apple.com? They have plenty of documentation, and also code examples and tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a chapter from Aaron Hillegass's book](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1211756) that shows how to do custom views and explains the view hierarchy.

There's also a ["View Programing Guide" available on Apple's web site](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978).

I'd very much recommend buying the [physical book of "Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619) and going through each of the chapters and doing each of the practice apps. You might think it expensive, but it's absolutely worth every penny. It one of those resources I used way back when I wanted to become a hardcore Cocoa engineer.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at these.  I think I know something of the theory, although I'm not an expert in any sense of the word.  What  I've found is that all programming eventually comes down to getting the exact code language in the exactly correct place. And then proof, reproof, and proof again.  There are so many sources that just give me pieces of the puzzle and I hope to find an exact set of steps for this task. I appreciate your help.